# order of (GNU) tar arguments under old style syntax?

Tags: tar

In a shell pipeline, I compose a tar archive from a selection of files under a directory, taking the list of files from stdin, and write the archive to stdout.  When I run `tar` like this:

```
tar cCTf directory - -
```

everything is fine.  But when I try to run it like this:

```
tar cTCf - directory -
```

`tar` does not find the files, and I get the following error message:

```
tar: The following options were used after any non-optional
arguments in archive create or update mode.  These options
are positional and affect only arguments that follow them.
Please, rearrange them properly.
tar: -C ‘directory' has no effect
```

What is wrong with the second command?

I am running GNU tar 1.34.

Comment: Are you able to install `bsdtar`?  `apt install bsdtar` then `bsdtar cTCf - directory - > output.tar` works on my Ubuntu test machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error...

> tar: The following options were used after any non-optional arguments in archive create or update mode.  These options are positional and affect only arguments that follow them.  Please, rearrange them properly.
>
> tar: -C ‘directory' has no effect

...is telling you that that the `C` option is position-dependent. It effect only options that come *after* it. So when you write `cTCf`, with `-C` after `-T`, it is effectively a no-op. It won't effect the way tar interprets filenames read by `-T`, and there's nothing after it to which it can apply.

This might be easier to understand when you consider that you can have multiple `-T` and `-C` options on the command line, e.g:

```
tar cCTCTf /path/to/dir1 filelist1 /path/to/dir2 filelist2 -
```

Each `-C` argument effects the following `-T` argument (but not any preceding ones).

Answer (score -1):

If you're not wedded to GNU tar, `bsdtar` does what you want, with your desired syntax:

```
$ find . -ls
 13107306    4 drwx--x---   3 user   grp       4096 Aug 30 12:54 .
 13107938    4 drwx--x---   2 user   grp       4096 Aug 30 12:38 ./directory
 13111189    4 -rw-------   1 user   grp         29 Aug 30 12:37 ./directory/a
 13113837    4 -rw-------   1 user   grp         29 Aug 30 12:37 ./directory/b
 13114062    4 -rw-------   1 user   grp         29 Aug 30 12:37 ./directory/c
$ printf "%s\n" a b c | bsdtar cTCf - directory - > output.tar
$ tar tvf output.tar 
-rw------- user/grp        29 2022-08-30 12:37 a
-rw------- user/grp        29 2022-08-30 12:37 b
-rw------- user/grp        29 2022-08-30 12:37 c
```